# how to display a listview based on the text inside the edittext with a clickable image button to search the listviews data?

Tags: android, listview

I have written a program to display a ListView. The Activity contains an EditText with a search button and ListView below. I have defined the items inside string.xml to be displayed inside the ListView:

```
<string-array name="Name2">
    <item>Name:Rohit Kumar</item>
    <item>Name:Rohit Kumar</item>
    <item>Name:Rohit Kumar</item>
    <item>Name:Rohit Kumar</item>
    <item>Name:Rohit Kumar</item>
    <item>Name:Rohit Kumar</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="Name3">
    <item>Name:Arjun Narahari</item>
    <item>Name:Arjun Narahari</item>
    <item>Name:Arjun Narahari</item>
    <item>Name:Arjun Narahari</item>
    <item>Name:Arjun Narahari</item>
    <item>Name:Arjun Narahari</item>
</string-array>
```

I have put it 6 times because inside my ListView I want to display the same name 6 times.

What my program does is, when I write "ar" inside my EditText and when I write "ro" or any timmed letter inside my EditText and click on search button, the results are displayed for the item which I have passed inside my custom adapter means for any case Arjun Narahari is only displayed and if I pass the rohit array, then for any case rohit is only displayed inside my ListView.

What I want my program to do is, when I write A or Ar inside my EditText and click on search button I want the results inside my ListView to be only starting from A or Ar and when I write R or Ro only those results should be displayed inside my ListView. 
Please, need some help.

Will post my code here:

Result_Name.java

```
public class Result_Name extends Activity {

 ImageView iv;
 EditText etSearch;
 private TextView txtNoResult;
 ImageView imgSearch;
 ResultsNameAdapter adapter;

 ListView lv;
 String[] name1, name2; // name3, name4, name5, name6;
 String[] mobile0, mobile1; // mobile2, mobile3, mobile4, mobile5;
 String[] age1, age2; // age3, age4, age5, age6;
 String[] gender;
 String[] diagname;
 String[] year;

 String PassedData;

 int[] images = {
  R.drawable.photo_bg,
  R.drawable.photo_bg,
  R.drawable.photo_bg,
  R.drawable.photo_bg,
  R.drawable.photo_bg,
  R.drawable.photo_bg,
  R.drawable.date,
  R.drawable.b_list,
  R.drawable.v_list,
  R.drawable.g_list
 };

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.result_listr_name);
   iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBackReuslt);
   etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearchName);
   imgSearch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSearchlist);

   Resources res = getResources();
   name1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Name1);

   name2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Name2);

   mobile0 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Mobile0);
   mobile1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Mobile1);

   age1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Age1);
   age2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.Age2);

   diagname = res.getStringArray(R.array.DiagnosisName);

   gender = res.getStringArray(R.array.Gender);
   year = res.getStringArray(R.array.year_array);

   etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearchName);

   etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSearchName);

   imgSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (etSearch.getText().toString().trim().length() < 0) {
      lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     }
     if (etSearch.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
      lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstResult);
      adapter = new ResultsNameAdapter(getBaseContext(), name1,
       name2, mobile0, mobile1, age1, age2, images, year,
       diagname, gender);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);

     }

    }

   });
```

The imgsearch is the image which I am using as a ClickListener and etsearch is my EditText. If my EditText is empty, my ListView is not visible and when my EditText has text with length > 0, my ListView is visible. This is where I want to change my things which I mentioned up.

I hope the requirements are clear.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i want my program to do is , when i write A or Ar inside my edittext and click on search button i want the results inside my listview to be only starting from A or Ar and when i write R or Ro only those results should be displayed inside my listview

A good way for you to achieve this and make it efficient is to use a [**`Trie`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure and you should look into that because explaining it is too broad for my SO answer.

Another way to reach to a simple solution would be to use the [**`String.startsWith`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method:

```
String text = etSearch.getText().toString().trim();
// check for "Rohit Kumar" array
for(String name : name2) {
    String nameWithoutLabel = name.substring(5); // skip the "Name:" part
    if(nameWithoutLabel.startsWith(text)) {
        // you will reach this point only if current nameWithoutLabel starts with the text from your EditText
        // add nameWithoutLabel to your list view or where you need it
    }
}
// same check for name3 which is the "Arjun Narahari" array
```

Another way you could check for `Strings` that start with a certain sequence is to use a regular expression:

```
// ...
if (nameWithoutLabel.matches("(" + text + ").*")) {
// ...
```

How you want to use the code above depends on how your `ResultsNameAdapter` is used and how you want to organize your data.

For example, what you can do is create a method out of the code above that finds `Strings` inside an array that starts with a certain text. Something like:

```
ArrayList<String> getMatches(String text, String[] names) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String name : names) {
        String nameWithoutLabel = name.substring(5); // skip the "Name:" part
        if(nameWithoutLabel.startsWith(text)) {
            list.add(nameWithoutLabel);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then you can call this method to find matches from whichever array you need to and store the matches in an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

// ...

String text = etSearch.getText().toString().trim();
allMatches.addAll(getMatches(text, name2)); // add all matches from name2
allMatches.addAll(getMatches(text, name3)); // add all matches from name3
// now ArrayList allMatches contains all matches from arrays name2 and name3
```

Now you can use the `ArrayList<String> allMatches` to populate your `ListView` inside your `ResultsNameAdapter`...